# Proper Syntax to Loop Through Core Data NSSet

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

Whenever I loop through my core data relations (NSSet) I have to either convert the set to an array:

```
for student in classroom.students.allObjects as! [Student] {
    print(student.name)
}
```

Or I can loop through the set normally but I have to typecast the item before I can use it:

```
for student in classroom.students {
    let s = student as! Student
    print(s.name)
}
```

I know this is trivial but all I want to do is simply pre-specify the cast for NSSet in the loop without having to do these work arounds?

When I try to do this:

```
for student: Student in classroom.students {
    print(student.name)
}
```

I get an error: **Expression type 'NSSet' is ambiguous without more context**

if I try something like this:

```
for student in classroom.students as! NSSet([Student]) {
    print(student.name)
}
```

I get an error: **Braced block of statements is an unused closure**

Is there a proper way to loop through an NSSet from Core Data and have the type pre-defined?

Comment: How is the property defined, presumably its autogenerated, when?

Comment: This question is about Core Data NSSet, so the property "Students" would be a one-to-many relationship between the Classroom and Student tables.

Comment: @TravisM. - I think Wain is asking how your property is defined in swift, assuming it is auto-generated by Xcode.  FWIW, you are casting each one in the "array" case as well, you are just doing it by casting the whole array to only include Student type.

Comment: I get that, but is the property defined with a type specifier on the set? I don't know if the auto generated version is now, I've never needed it for this, but if it can be it should resolve your issue

Comment: You never needed to do this? Yeah, my model is generated by Xcode and the type is "@NSManaged var students: NSSet?". How do you get yours defined? Do you do it manually?

Comment: I'm not a swiftie, but you should be able to define the property as `Set<Student>` and then you won't need to cast it when you use it.

Comment: Bah, wish the auto-generator did that for me automatically... My dataset changes so much that it's hard to justify manually overwriting any areas. But this is great to know for the future when it's stable. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that the `students` relationship is a to-many relationship to `Student`, you can cast the relationship to a Swift set using generic-style syntax:

```
for student in classroom.students! as! Set<Student> {
    print(student.name)
}
```

Comment: Confirmed this works! Thanks!  (I don't think you need that first "!")

Comment: Those exclamation (question) marks hurt my eyes... the primary reason I have avoided swift until I am forced to use it.